# problem of getting url of loading html page (c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, winforms

Well,

I develop a native browser and i've got a problem with a site navigated on this browser.

An input["type"]-button click post an httprequest to obtain and show an other page in a new tab (onglet).

I'm trying several methods but the TabPageof webBrowser is blank and I've got a IE explorer window opening.

here the code

```
 private void Browser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
 webBrowser22 = (WebBrowser)sender;
            if (webBrowser22.Document != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement tag in webBrowser22.Document.All)
                {
 HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser22.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

                for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
                {
                    HtmlElement el = elements[i];
                    string elType = el.GetAttribute("type");

                    switch (elType)
                    {
                        case "radio":
                        case "checkbox":
                        case "button":
                            {
                                el.MouseUp += new HtmlElementEventHandler(link_MouseUpPup);
                                
                            }
}}}}

private void link_MouseUpPup(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.tb2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.webBrowser221 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
           
            var linky = (HtmlElement)sender;
            mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement ba = (mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement)linky.DomElement;

       
            //  if ((ba.target != null && ba.target.ToLower() == "_blank") || e.ShiftKeyPressed || e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Middle)

            //if (Regex.Match(e.ReturnValue.ToString(), "http:").Value != null || Regex.Match(e.ReturnValue.ToString(), "https:").Value != null)
            
                tabControl1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { this.tb2 });
                tb2.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { this.webBrowser221 });
                webBrowser221.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

1ERE METHODE----
                //webBrowser221.Navigate(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
2EME METHODE----                
//webBrowser221.Navigate(ba.href);
3EME METHODE----
                // webBrowser221.Navigate(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString());
4EME METHODE----               
// webBrowser221.Navigate(e.ToElement.GetAttribute("onclick").ToString());
                
tb2.Text = e.ToElement.GetAttribute("onclick").ToString();
                tb2.ToolTipText = webBrowser221.StatusText;
            }
```

The problem is that I would opening the site page loading by the click input after his process (the process is been programmed in html and javascript with the function window.open and the property target="_blank") by the c# control webBrowser.

who's the problem, it's ie explorer that is opening instead of webBrowser window.

thanks your for your help.

M.A.

Comment: for this webBrowser control, the method execute the click button but it is not executing the script javascript associatéd to this click button.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I used the package reference "SHDocVm" of "Microsoft Internet Controls" and I place a function handler NewWindow3 after the case button and it's ok, a window.open() javascript function with target="_blank" opens a new page of webBrowser.

Truly yours.

M.A.